# How to submit a Form by using a textlink POST method

Tags: php, html, hyperlink, form-submit

I'm new to PHP but was wondering how this can be done.

I want to have submit an HTML form to another PHP page, but i dont want to use the ugly button. I want to use a link.

The thing is, i see many solutions out there that uses Java Script/Jquery etc to solve this, Does any one know how to do this with PHP code and HTML only?

Comment: PHP is server-side, so no matter how much you tried, it is impossible to do. HTML, however, *could* have done this, but it unfortunately does not, so you would have to stick with at least some minor JavaScript coding (see Sarfraz' answer)

Comment: Or you could actually try to style your submit button with css.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Either use a `<input type="submit">` and style it like a link with css, or create a Link with onclick:

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.forms['name_of_your_form'].submit();">Lol Rofl</a>
```

If you want to make sure it works when JS is disabled, add something like this:

```
<noscript>
    <input type="submit" ... />
</noscript>
```

This will show the button on computers where JS is disabled, the link above will still be shown. A workaround is to hide the link with CSS and then show it with JS..

Comment: The thing is, i wanted it to work without javascript. Notjavascript, and no button. Is there any possible way to do this using the link and PHP code?

Comment: @Relik Angus: no, PHP can't since it's server-side only, and HTML cannot because it hasn't been implemented - that is why we use JavaScript to do this after all.

Comment: No. Except you are pleased with the results you get by styling the submit button with CSS, which has nothing to do with Javascript and should be supported / enabled on every browser. -- Like I wrote:  "use a <input type='submit'> and style it like a link with css", which is basically the same as gordon says.

Comment: Yea. cool. I just got what you both were saying. I'll try this way. Thanks a mill.

Comment: Chose this response cuz its a combination of @Sarfraz's and Gordon's.. use Javascript and make the button look like a link.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this way:

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.forms['form_name'].submit();">Submit</a>
```

That will submit the form to whatever url set in the `action` attribute of the `form`.

Comment: that may work, but isnt this Java script? I kinda wanted a solution in PHP/html

Comment: @Relik Angus: PHP is server-side language, you can not use it to submit forms :)

Comment: Oh aright Sarfraz. Thanks. guess i'll have to work with jscript :/

Answer (score 3):

I dont know how much Buttons are capable of being styled in a uniform way across all browser, but here is a start/proof of concept you can fiddle with, read: test, adjust, put into external CSS, and so on

```
<input type="submit" value="Send" style="
    border:0;
    background-color:transparent;
    color: blue;
    text-decoration:underline;
"/>
```

Comment: this is just crazy enough to work.. Style a button that looks like a link huh. Aright then ^^ thanks k.  I'll try this

Answer (score 1):

I found an alternative way of using plain text as a submit button, by trial and (a lot of) error. Put label tags around the submit button and the text, then define the button CSS so it doesn't display and the text CSS so it looks like a link.

Bear in mind that this is probably not good practise at all. :)

For example, this goes in the HTML form:

```
<label class="notalink"><input type="submit" value="Submit" class="invisibutton">
Click this text to submit</label>
```

And this goes in the CSS:

```
.invisibutton {
    height: 1px;
    width: 1px;
    display: none;
    vertical-align: text-bottom;
}

label {
    color: (link-color)
    text-decoration: (etc.)
}
```

And so on for the label definition so it looks like a standard link. The button is invisible but the text is clickable as its label, so it acts like a button.

The one downside is that it made my label text drop a pixel. If there were other words around the pseudo-link, I had to define the surrounding text class with a "vertical-align: bottom;" to make sure it didn't look weird.

Worked a charm, though. I successfully used it in a WordPress page to create fake links that kick off php scripts (by setting $_POST).